# Fix up manged git flow

Tags: git

When I do a git log I have this output:

> *   6e357b7
>   |\
>   |  * c2aeb5a
>   |  * dd4f8c3
>   |  * e00e7d9
>   *  | b6453b0
>   |/
>   * f29ad8d

I have no idea how I managed this.  I want this to just be a straight line from the bottom commit to the top, without that branching.  If it makes it easier to fix, the b6453b0 can just be removed as there wasn't actually anything valid in that commit.

Everything I try with rebasing and cherry picking just makes things worse.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The tip of the current branch is 6e357b7? And you then don't want to have the merge revision at all, right?

You might do this:

```
git checkout f29ad8d
git cherry-pick b6453b0..c2aeb5a # drop b6453b0
```

If you like the result

```
git branch -f some-branch HEAD
git checkout some-branch
```

Comment: That actually causes another branch to appear.  So strange.  I'm going to just leave it alone.  Bleh.